# nodemon is not watching when change in text in js file in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, nodemon

```
package.json

{
  "name": "nodemon-docker-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start:express": "node ./index.js",
    "start": "nodemon"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.2"
  }
}


Dockerfile

FROM node:slim

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN apt-get update
RUN npm install

COPY . /app
# -or-
# COPY . .

EXPOSE 1337
CMD ["npm", "start"]



docker-compose.yml

version: '3.1'

services:
    node:
        build: .
        volumes:
        - ./:/app
        ports: 
            - 1337:1337
        working_dir: /app
        expose:
        - "1337"
```

1. **docker-compose up** - first i am build node web app with this command.
2. **docker run --rm -it  -p 1337:1337/tcp nodemon-docker-test_node:latest** - then i am running using this command

I m not getting that what i am doing wrong in here, server.js is running with nodemon after 
run command in docker but it is not watching the changes that i am doing in server.js or it is not restarting the server after making the changes.
please correct me if i am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell nodemon what file to run like so:

```
"start": "nodemon ./index.js"
```

Comment: bro it is not working , i rebuild the image again but nodemon is still not watching the changes